# Arduino-izing LEGO Technic - and now I need some ideas for the Lego Service Truck 8071

Tags: motor, electronics, arduino, technic

I am starting a project - Arduino-izing LEGO Technic - and now I need some ideas for a car / vehicle to choose.

This project starts out as a quest to find a way to combine the ease of LEGO Technic chassis building with cheap commodity electronics to motorize and remote control it.

I was looking for a vehicle that is able to work for this. This could be a simple chassis: https://www.instructables.com/id/Build-your-own-Custom-Arduino-Remote-Control-and-L/ https://www.hackster.io/Notthemarsian/take-control-over-lego-power-functions-ee0bfa https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Remote-Controlled-Car-1/

[image]

This should be a part of a robotics workshop and therefore I need a LEGO-based platform for younger kids who grew up with Lego but cannot afford to spend hundreds of dollars to buy power functions, LEGO motors, IR remote, and EV3. Thanks to numerous examples on the net and several and Youtube tutorials on integrating Arduino with LEGO, I will try to start out with an interesting example.
Starting point: the kids should be able to complete this project with a small budget and I hope to incorporate this into my robotics workshop in the future.
The main thing is, I need to have the rear axle to be attached to a single N20 motor to move the kart forward and reverse via a TB6612FNG motor driver. Front steering can be controlled by an SG90 servo motor.

i have chosen the Lego Service Truck 8071 - see here:  https://www.lego.com/de-de/service/buildinginstructions/search?initialsearch=8071&ignorereferer=true#?text=8071

Remote control should be able to be accomplished by a cheap IR remote/receiver solution based on

Arduino
Zigbee
Bluetooth

I understand that the IR remote hardware (and the method) is pretty hard part to implement and learn about a remote control system so it was a perfect option for this car.

Since this is just a proof-of-concept project and the design follows function - I need to have an idea.

The main question is: How about LEGO Technic-8071 - the Service Truck?

guess that i can add the steering and motor with ease

[image]

[image]

[image]

many many thanks for all the hints - [image]

Comment: Your question could use some clarity. You mention you are interested in keeping cost down. For the chassis design, do you need/want it to be a set? Or, can it be a oversimplified MOC?  Or, are you just wanting the design to have instructions?

Comment: hello dear JonnyB - many thanks for the reply. Great to hear from you. I need some tipps for the design and i would be glad to get some ideas where to put the engines ... Many thanks in advance for any and all help - greetings zero

Comment: @zero I'd rather disassemble this set and start with a simple frame. Something like two liftarms, two axles, four wheels. Have the kids position the motor to make the car go forward and reverse. At this stage you can still use rubber bands to attach the motor and drive the wheels. Next introduce a simple steering mechanism and add it. And so on...

Comment: @zero also make sure to check out *Yoshihito Isogawa*'s brilliant book: **The Lego Power Functions Idea Book Volume Two - Cars and Contraptions**

Comment: hello dear uli hello dear all - many thanks for the hints - i am happy about all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after doing some research I think the most helpful solution I can offer is a picture of various techniques and a link to a straight-forward, budget friendly tutorial. I think trying to explain anything in depth would be tedious and vulnerable to misinterpretation. It also appears that super glue, hot glue, and some pieces to sacrifice/modify will be necessary.
The link: https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-izing-Lego-Technic-Go-Kart/
Pic:
[image]

Comment: hello JonnyB - wow  this is just overwhelming. Many many thanks - i  am very glad. This is the wanted and needed push for the project.  Great!  - many thanks for all you did!!

Comment: many thanks for all the hints -